# Create an index on a materialized view in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

How do you create a index on a materialized view in Amazon Redshift? I see the documentation for creating a materialized index, but there is no indication on whether or not indexes are supported: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/materialized-view-create-sql-command.html

Answer (score 2):

Redshift doesn't have indexes.

You can configure [distribution keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Distributing_data.html) and [sort keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Sorting_data.html), which provide *some* of the functionality of indexes.

A traditional B-Tree index would rarely be appropriate for the sorts of queries that you'd use Redshift for (which tend to be all-rows joins between large tables).